# Why was my shogi question closed and then later re-opened? Who was wrong, and why?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I did spend a lot of time to write that 2nd xiangqi post.

[The Chess960 analogue in shogi, xiangqi, etc](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/33843/the-chess960-analogue-in-shogi-xiangqi-etc)

[The Chess960 analogue in xiangqi](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41448/the-chess960-analogue-in-xiangqi)

Hope this site will not be so hasty in closing questions by too broad. This is kinda what happened here [Chessmaster: Modern version of lectures?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/35639/chessmaster-modern-version-of-lectures) and even other SE sites. I notice moderators just close any post with 2 question marks when it's quite obvious what is meant.

In my opinion https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/35641/practical-endgame-resources-whats-next-after-josh-waitzkins-series-in-chess suffered the same fate. See here: [Why was the endgame post deleted 9 minutes ago?](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1140/why-was-the-endgame-post-deleted-9-minutes-ago)

Answer (score 2):

I reverted some of the edits to the shogi question because the edits made the answers obsolete.

Generally speaking if two questions differ only with by a single word there's not a reason to have both of them.

The question itself is extremely long (which is why it was closed as needing focus), but it has received good answers.

Comment: 'Generally speaking if two questions differ only with by a single word there's not a reason to have both of them.' --> sure? https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/92181/according-to-mormon-church-can-co-parents-in-law-marry and https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/76130/does-the-mormon-church-endorse-the-children-of-narcissistic-parents-breaking-off and https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/46565/does-the-catholic-church-endorse-the-children-of-narcissistic-parents-breaking-o It's common to ask the same question for diff denominations in Christianity SE.

Comment: Ah so the close is NOT REALLY about because I asked about both shogi and xiangqi? Lol srzly? So why wasn't the close needs details or clarity instead of too broad?

Comment: @BCLC In my opinion, the "needs details or clarity" would have been a better reason in this particular case. Notice, that the wording in "Needs more focus" is also quite applicable, it is that usually this is used to indicate "multiple questions in one", but it is not 100% consistent. 

My general recommendation would be to pay extra attention to the clarity in the questions/answers, including conciseness where it is possible.

Comment: @AntonMenshov ' In my opinion, the "needs details or clarity" would have been a better reason in this particular case.' --> ok thanks. post as answer?

Comment: @BCLC Lol, the link to Christianity SE has a comment from one of their mods asking why you are separating these questions :)