# Why was the endgame post deleted 9 minutes ago?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Here's the post:

https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/35641/practical-endgame-resources-whats-next-after-josh-waitzkins-series-in-chess

I was just submitting an edit for re-opening after this close reason [Why was my shogi question closed and then later re-opened? Who was wrong, and why?](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1139/why-was-my-shogi-question-closed-and-then-later-re-opened-who-was-wrong-and-wh). Then now what?

Answer (score 3):

The post was deleted because the edits were simply trying to game the review queue.

It's not reasonable to expect site users to spend time and review questions after changing numbers.